# Why _Layout.cshtml placed in ~/Views/Shared folder by default?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Why `_Layout.cshtml` placed in `~/Views/Shared` folder by default?

I ask this question because I put this file in `~/Views` folder and change the `Layout` value in the `_ViewStart.cshtml`

```
@{
    Layout = "~/views/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

and it still work.

Is it for a special purpose that `_Layout.cshtml` placed in `~/Views/Shared` folder by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the layout page is referenced by its full path, you are right that it makes no difference where it is, as long as it's somewhere under the ~/Views folder.

One situation where it would matter (but it often doesn't), is when in your controller action you call the overload of "View()" that allows you to specify an alternate layout (master) page. If that's the case, and the name specified is a "simple" name, such as "MobileLayout", the default search path will be first the current controller's view folder, and then the Shared views folder.

Another much simpler reason is that it "makes sense" in terms of conventions, regardless of any technical requirements.

Answer (score 1):

By convention, the `/views/shared` folder is for views that are, well, *shared* by different controllers, such as layouts and reusable partials. As you have seen, there's no reason you can't put layouts whereever you want, as long as you reference them properly.

Answer (score 1):

- If you put the `_Layout.cshtml` in `Views` folder then you have to specify its file extension explicitly in `Layout="_Layout.cshtml"`.
- If you put the `_Layout.cshtml` in `Views/Shared` or `Views/XXX` folder then you must **NOT** specify its file extension explicitly in `Layout="_Layout"`.